# How to submit Android app with specific date for very first time release on Google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have an android app which we want to submit for review for the first time.  However, the client doesn't want it to be released right away. On iTunes connect, there is an option to release the app manually once the app is approved.

How can we do the same thing or the Android store?

Comment: This isn't a customer-service question, it's asking how to use a developer tool.

Comment: I agree with @Ryan M that it is not a customer service related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on Managed Publishing in the Play Console.

On your app, go to "Publishing Overview" > Click Manage on "Managed publishing status" > Select "Managed publishing on" > Click Save.

This will allow the changes to be reviewed without being published straight away. You will then be able to publish the changes in the "Publishing Overview" section.